# How to run TeamSpeak3 server on boot?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, teamspeak

I'm trying to run TeamSpeak3 server on boot. I have ts3server script put in */etc/init.d*. It works if I type *ts3server start* but it doesn't work on boot. What's more it shuts down on reboot so only starting does work.
To set it I've used:

```
update-rc.d setdatetime defaults
```

Did I do something wrong? Here is the code of script:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: teamspeak
# Required-Start: $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $network
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Description: Teamspeak 3 Server
### END INIT INFO

USER="ts3"
DIR="/home/ts3/teamspeak3-server_linux-amd64"
###### Teamspeak 3 server start/stop script ######
case "$1" in
start)
su $USER -c "$DIR/ts3server_startscript.sh start"
;;
stop)
su $USER -c "$DIR/ts3server_startscript.sh stop"
;;
restart)
su $USER -c "$DIR/ts3server_startscript.sh restart"
;;
status)
su $USER -c "$DIR/ts3server_startscript.sh status"
;;
*)
echo "Usage: " >&2
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
ts3server start
```

to the end of that file.

You might want to put it in a screen:

```
screen -u 1 ts3server start
```

If I were you I would leave the startup script exactly where it is. As I have done on my server. I only added the following line to my /etc/init.d/

```
screen -u 1 ./ts3server/ts3server_minimal_runscript.sh
```